# laravel NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am new at laravel. I am trying to make a link to another page. I have the page index and want to go to desc which display information about a vehicle selected in index page.
The problem is that it shows the error:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

```
index.blade.php

    @foreach ($cars as $car)
           <tr>                                   
           <td> 
           {{link_to_action('CarController@show',  $car->Description, $car->id)}}</td>  
             {{ Form::open(array('action' => 'CarController@show', $car->id)) }}
                  {{ Form::close() }}
                        <td>{{ $car->License }}</td>  
                        <td>{{ $car->Milage }}</td> 
                        <td>{{ $car->Make }}</td>  
                        <td>{{ $car->status }}</td>                                    
          </tr>                                                            
    @endforeach
```

routes.php

```
Route::resource('/', 'CarController');
Route::resource('create', 'DataController');
Route::post('desc', array('uses' => 'CarController@show'));
Route::post('create', array('uses' => 'CarController@create', 'uses' => 'DataController@index'));
Route::post('update', array('uses' => 'CarController@update'));
Route::post('store', array('store' => 'CarController@store'));
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The 'NotFoundHttpException' means Laravel wasn't able to find a route to for the request.

Your `desc` route is a POST route, only, and a `link_to_action` will create a GET request, so you may need to change add a GET route too:

```
Route::post('desc', array('uses' => 'CarController@show'));
Route::get('desc', array('uses' => 'CarController@show'));
```

There's also a `any`, which does GET, POST, PUT, DELETE:

```
Route::any('desc', array('uses' => 'CarController@show'));
```

If you need to get and `id` from your route, you will have to add it as a parameter:

```
Route::post('car/{id}', array('uses' => 'CarController@show'));
```

And you will have to access your page as:

```
http://myappt.al/public/car/22
```

But if you want to access it as:

```
http://myappt.al/public/22
```

You'll need to do:

```
Route::post('{id}', array('uses' => 'CarController@show'));
```

**But this one is dangerous**, because it will may grab all the routes, so you **MUST to set it as your very last route**.

And your controller must accept that parameter:

```
class CarController extends Controller {

   public function show($id)
   {
      dd("I received an ID of $id");
   }
}
```

EDIT:

Since you most of your routes made manually, you can also go with the index this way:

```
Route::resource('create', 'DataController'); 

Route::get('/', 'CarController@index');

Route::post('create', array('uses' => 'CarController@create','uses' => 'DataController@index')); 
Route::post('update', array('uses' => 'CarController@update')); 
Route::post('store', array('store' => 'CarController@store')); 

Route::get('{id}', array('uses' => 'CarController@show'));
Route::post('{id}', array('uses' => 'CarController@show'));
```

Comment: but the route is : http://myappt.al/public/22 it is not http://myapp.al/public/desc. It gets the id

Comment: You need to add a parameter to your route, edited to show how.

Comment: Edited again to clarify.

Comment: i had Route::resource('cars', 'CarController'); and it worked perfectly. http://localhost/national/public/cars/21 this was the path. now that my Route::resource('/', 'CarController') the path to desc page is : http://localhost/national/public/21 and shows this error

Comment: can you show me another way? instead of id in my path to be the name of page? for example http://myappt.al/public/desc ?? not to show the id

Comment: Route::resource('/', 'CarController');
Route::resource('create', 'DataController');
Route::post('create', array('uses' => 'CarController@create','uses' => 'DataController@index'));
Route::post('update', array('uses' => 'CarController@update'));
Route::post('store', array('store' => 'CarController@store'));
Route::post('{id}', array('uses' => 'CarController@show'));

Comment: Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: I just edited to show you a list of routes that may work for you, the route::get was missing, and I think that the index could be done manually too. Check my edit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51893/discussion-between-antonio-carlos-ribeiro-and-user3592644)

Comment: could you suggest me another way of doing this? wothout showing the id at url?

Comment: Could you get to the chat?

Comment: it shows the same error for the page after dec. which is edit

Comment: Please, click here to go the the chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51893/discussion-between-antonio-carlos-ribeiro-and-user3592644