# How can allow the method in routes using laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to execute the method but it does not working. I know it is very basic and may be ask more time, but i didn't resolve.

### Controller

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class LockController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Show the profile for the given user.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        return view('lock');
    }

    public function login()
    {


        return view('login');
    }

}
?>
```

### Route

```
Route::get('/lock', 'LockController@index');
Route::get('/lock', 'LockController@login');
```

This `Route::get('/lock', 'LockController@index');` route working fine using this `http://localhost/laravelDev/public/index.php/lock` url but another route does not working properly and i'm getting this error `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:`. For login method i'm using this url `http://localhost/laravelDev/public/index.php/lock/login`.

I searched about it, i follow the instruction of this accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430205/laravel-notfoundhttpexception) but it does not work, can any one guide me where i'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have two identicals routes for different methods? I don't think that should work.

I could work if one was `get` and the other `post`.

Also, usualy, the url is would be `http://localhost/lock` or `http://localhost/lock/login`. The `public/index.php` shouldn't be necessaire.

Change the second route to this, pretty sure it'll work:
    Route::get('/lock/login', 'LockController@login');

Answer (score 0):

You can mention the required methods which will be handled in controller file(s) in routes.php file.

Example:
 
Route::get('url/of/the/resource', 'controllername@action'); (o handle 'GET' requests). 
Route::post('url/of/the/resource', 'controllername@action'); (For 'POST' requests).

Details: 
Route::get('/user/register', 'UserController@showRegistrationForm');
This indicates to show a registration from when given url (When GET request is made) is given like below:. 
http://localhost/your_laravel_project_folder/user/register 
Route::post('/user/register', 'UserController@handleUserRegistration');
This indicates to handle the registration from data when user submits the registration form. (When POST request is made).

class UserController extends Controller 
{
  
     public function showRegistrationForm()
           {
                  return view('User.register');
             }
  
     public function handleUserRegistration()
           {
                  $registerInput      =   Input::all();
          var_dump($registerInput);
             }
}