# {message: "", exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException",…}

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm a newbie in laravel. I want to add a product using ajax method but I'm getting this error, in the console: `POST 404 NOT FOUND`. In the network, I'm getting this error message:

```
{message: "", exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException",…}
exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException"
file: "C:\Users\rolan\Desktop\Laravel Tutorial\Fims\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php"
line: 179
message: ""
trace: [{,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…},…]
```

Here is my ajax code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // alert("working");
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        var prodName = $("#prodName").val();
        var rate = $("#rate").val();
        var beginningQuantity = $("#beginningQuantity").val();
        var token = $("#token").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "prodName=" + prodName + "&rate=" + rate + "&beginningQuantity=" + beginningQuantity + "&_token" + token,
            url: "<?php echo url('/saveProduct') ?>",
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

here's the line 179 codes

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{csrf_token()}}" id="token">
```

here's the controller code

```
public function saveProduct(Request $request){
    return $request;
}
```

here's the route

```
Route::get('/adminIndex',"adminIndexController@count");
Route::get('/adminInventory',"adminInventoryController@count");
```

Comment: is that the laravel code ?!!?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430205/laravel-notfoundhttpexception

Comment: View the rendered source of your page and see what the actual `url` value for your ajax function is.  Make sure it is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Which route is actually used to send the request to?

Answer (score 2):

NotFoundHttpException usually means that your route doesn't exist. Check your web.php file and make sure that there is a route there for '/saveProduct' and that it is a post route and not a get route.

You will need a route like this:

```
Route::post('/saveProduct', 'adminInventoryController@saveProduct');
```

Comment: Laslomcd, perhaps provide a code example of what the POST route could/should look like as example? It would help with the context of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it, but it seems as though you may have incorrectly typed it into your question, but you have written:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: "prodName=" + prodName + "&rate=" + rate + "&beginningQuantity=" + beginningQuantity + "&_token" + token,
    url: "<?php echo url('/saveProduct') ?>",
    succes: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Is it meant to say `success:` instead of `succes:`?

Comment: I edited it but still has the same problem anyways thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me using hyphens or underscore instead of camel case did the trick

```
Route::post('/save-product', 'adminInventoryController@saveProduct');
```